# How to close a modal component after some seconds?

Tags: svelte, sveltekit, svelte-3, svelte-store

I've created a modal that is controlled by an svelte store.

```
//store.js
export let modal = writable({
    show: false,
    message: 'This is a simple modal... will update the message before shows to user'
})


//Modal.svelte

<script>
    import { afterUpdate, beforeUpdate, onMount} from 'svelte';

    beforeUpdate(() => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            $modal.show = false
    }, 4000)
    })
</script>


{#if $modal.show}
    <div class="fixed">
        {$modal.message}
    </div>
{/if}
```

After the first update, it closes very fast not respecting the 4000ms.
What have I done wrong? Is there a better way to make a notification modal?

Answer (score 1):

If you have one store you can only ever have one modal instance. `show` should just be a property of the `Modal` component, not a separate store.

Also `beforeUpdate` is *not* what you should use at all, that will fire for any and all state changes. The timer management should probably be outside the component or in encapsulated in an exported function that can be called on demand. It depends on why the delay should be there in the first place.

If you want to create a passive notification, `Modal` is the wrong name. Modals are for transactional user interaction. For a notification I would set up a timer in `onMount` that fires a a `close` [event](https://svelte.dev/docs#run-time-svelte-createeventdispatcher) and whatever created the component detroys the notification upon receiving the event.

So the calling code would look something like:

```js
function notification(message) {
   const component = new Notification({
       target: document.body,
       props: { message },
   );
   component.$on('close', () => component.$destroy());
}
```